# Can I Map a Network Drive on a server to itself (SharePoint Server)?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, sharepoint, windows-server-2012-r2, mappeddrive

I'm running a Windows 2012 64bit Server R2, computer name *server-01*, and I want to map a network drive to a path located on the same server. (This is needed for SharePoint 2013 development.)

[image: Map Network Drive]

However, I get the typical *Windows cannot access [url]* Network Error prompt. (Diagnosing it yields no details).

[image: Network Error]

I can map the drive to a client computer (outside of the server) using the server's public URL, i.e. http://publicurl/_catalogs/masterpage . Also, the account that I am using is an administrator account. It can also be noted that the *server-01* is a web server (IIS), and a domain controller. (It's a development server, not production). I guess I could make it that I connect to the drive from the public URL, but I'm still curious why this isn't working.

**Edit:**
I cannot map a network drive remotely. I thought I could, but I can't; sorry for the mislead information.

Comment: Are there any interesting failures in the server's security log when the authentication attempt happens?  And what does the IIS configuration (specifically, what host headers and IP listeners are configured for what sites) look like?

Comment: @HopelessN00b It's a WebDAV mount

Comment: Oh, duh.  Probably no DNS suffix appending.  Does it work by IP, or with the FQDN rather than just hostname?

Comment: Don't have a way to test your particular case here, but I feel like you could try:

a)  Write a host file entry that points 'server-01' back to localhost, or 
b)  Just use localhost in that "Folder" section there in your screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error ended up being directly related to SharePoint, and having multiple types of authentication enabled (i.e. forms auth and windows auth). The remedy ended up being that you must use a browser (i.e. Internet Explorer) to authenticate against the server, then keep the browser open so you're credentials remain in tact. After this, you will be able to map the drive.

This goes for both mapped drives from the client to the server server, and mapping a network drive to itself on a server.

Reference: http://www.sharepointblogs.be/blogs/vandest/archive/2013/02/06/sharepoint-and-claims-map-network-drive-issue.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable Desktop Experience feature after that you can map as drive that SharePoint url. The steps are [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/rmilne/archive/2013/07/11/install-desktop-experience-on-windows-server-2012.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

do not "network" map it
open cmd and type

> subst Z: d:\local\path\to\your\share\

that will do what you wish for :)